# How to disable Win+F built-in action (not hotkey by it self) and use Win+F in other programs?

Tags: autohotkey

I don't use Win+F built-in action to open file explorer with search panel, so I would like to use this shortcut in "Sublime Text 2" specifying shortcut action with its internal key binding mechanism.

I tried this:

```
#f::Return
```

but it just disables Win+F, "Sublime Text 2" can't use it, then I tried this:

```
#f::
if WinActive("ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS")
{
   Send {LWin down}{f}{LWin Up}
}
Return
```

but now just in "Sublime Text 2" Win+F opens explorer.

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Petras**

> ...how to make Win+F available for Sublime?

As a way:

```
#If, WinActive("ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS")
   #vk46:: ; win+f as "toggle_side_bar" command
      Send, {CtrlDown}{vk4B}{vk42}{CtrlUp} ; ctrldn+k+b+ctrlup
      KeyWait, vk46
      Return
;~ #If ; if has any hotkey/s below...
```

---

Edit:

```
; ...
; //{ "keys": ["f3"], "command": "find_next" },
; { "keys": ["super+`"], "command": "find_next" },
; ...

#vk46::
   Send, % WinActive("ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS") ? "#{vkC0}":""
   KeyWait, vk46
   Return
```

Comment: Thank You, cooool :) it is working :)
but in fact I would like to send to Sublime the same hotkey #f or #vk46, and to disable #f globaly, so I makeover:

`#vk46::
   if WinActive("ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS") {
      Send, {LWin Down}{vk46}{LWin Up}
      KeyWait, vk46
   }
Return`

I have got #f globaly disabled, but in Sublime #f opens windows file explorer and don't trigger Sublime's command, in my `User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` is `{ "keys": ["super+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "incremental_find", "reverse":false} }`

Comment: **Petras** wrote:

"...in fact I would like to send to Sublime the same hotkey #f or #vk46, and to disable #f globaly..."
"I have got #f globaly disabled..."

Since you will not be able to use the native key combination Win + F (it's just not possible), you can use a similar combination (binding in any *.sublime-keymap file) such as Win + Tilde, and so on. I have edited the code above.